# SQL Query optimalisation Merge Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Problem: one of my queries is really slow, I can't get my head around it.

**Context**: I have made the following database. We want to combine all these tables, they do not have the same columns at all. so no Union, we don't want to lose any data cause the intend is to get an overview of what we need to 'clean up' so we used full join to create the merge table.

Database overview

1. Dim data

   - merge ( inner join of the columns below)
   - users
   - roles
   - entitlements
2. Peach database

   - merge
   - user
   - role
   - contract (this table has an objID we need later)
3. Cics

   - Consolidated users
4. HR

   - Zuordnung
   - users
5. Merge

   - Merge

The 'slow' query:

(in the actual report we build we have a filter on role, fachteam, team, abteilung, bereich, geschaeftsbereich, konzernbereich) but let's keep it simple with this where statement

```
select 
    count(distinct CentralAccount) as 'aantal users',  
    count(distinct [Rol naam]) as 'aantal rollen',
    [FTM], [Fachteam], [TEM], [Team], 
    [ABT], [Abteilung], [BER], [Bereich], [GB], [Geschaeftsbereich],
    [KB], [Konzernbereich]
from 
    [ODS_ISRC].[dbo].[Merge]
where 
    CentralAccount is not null 
    and ftm is not null 
group by 
    [FTM], [Fachteam], [TEM], [Team],
    [ABT], [Abteilung], [BER], [Bereich],
    [GB], [Geschaeftsbereich], [KB], [Konzernbereich]
order by 
    count(distinct CentralAccount) desc
```

What is slow?

The current execution time is 49-50 seconds (client statistics).

What I have tried:

We already have a clustered key: `ID, primary key, identity (1,1)`

The query statistic showed me that it is creating an index, so I have tried pre creating this index so it would increase the performance, well I was wrong there, it somehow took sql 5 seconds (10%) longer to execute.

```
create nonclustered index test
on dbo.[Merge] (FTM, centralaccount)
include ([Fachteam],[TEM],[Team],[ABT],[Abteilung],[BER],[Bereich],[GB],[Geschaeftsbereich],[KB],[Konzernbereich], [rol naam])
```

Question:

Is there anyway I can increase the performance of this query without pre creating the table?

Extra information:

The query runs (acceptable) fast when there is data filled into the report filters, but the user usually wants an overview before filtering.

Execution plan:

- [Plan only pk index](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1B26Hd8M)
- [Plan with Index](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJwSlUuLf)

Actual report query:

```
select 
    count(distinct CentralAccount) as 'aantal users',  
    count(distinct [Rol naam]) as 'aantal rollen',
    [FTM], [Fachteam], [TEM], [Team],
    [ABT], [Abteilung], [BER], [Bereich],
    [GB], [Geschaeftsbereich], [KB], [Konzernbereich]
from 
    [ODS_ISRC].[dbo].[Merge]
where 
    CentralAccount is not null and ftm is not null 
    and (@Role = '' and ([Rol naam] like '%'+@Role+'%' or [Rol naam] is null)  
         or @Role = '' and (Role_Beschrijving like '%'+@Role+'%' or Role_Beschrijving is null) 
         or [Rol naam] like '%'+@Role+'%' or Role_Beschrijving like '%'+@Role+'%')
    and (@Team='' and (Team like '%'+@Team+'%' or Team is null) or
         @Team is not null and (Team like '%'+@Team+'%')or
         @Team is null and ( Team is null))
    and (@Fachteam='' and (Fachteam like '%'+@Fachteam+'%' or Fachteam is null) or
         @Fachteam is not null and (Fachteam like '%'+@Fachteam+'%')or
         @Fachteam is null and ( Fachteam is null))
    and (@Abteilung='' and (Abteilung like '%'+@Abteilung+'%' or Abteilung is null) or
         @Abteilung is not null and (Abteilung like '%'+@Abteilung+'%')or
         @Abteilung is null and ( Abteilung is null))
    and (@Bereich='' and (Bereich like '%'+@Bereich+'%' or Bereich is null) or
         @Bereich is not null and (Bereich like '%'+@Bereich+'%')or
         @Bereich is null and ( Bereich is null))
    and (@Geschaeftsbereich='' and (Geschaeftsbereich like  '%'+@Geschaeftsbereich+'%' or Geschaeftsbereich is null) or
         @Geschaeftsbereich is not null and (Geschaeftsbereich like   '%'+@Geschaeftsbereich+'%') or
         @Geschaeftsbereich is null and ( Geschaeftsbereich is null))
group by 
    [FTM], [Fachteam], [TEM], [Team], [ABT], [Abteilung],
    [BER], [Bereich], [GB], [Geschaeftsbereich], [KB], [Konzernbereich]
order by 
    count(distinct CentralAccount) desc
```

Comment: Can you share the execution plan using this tool and include it in your question https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: What is rowcount in {[dbo].[Merge]} and is there any date column ?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze the execution plan has been shared; @B house 1 319 072 records, there are datetimecolumns in [dbo].[merge] but they are not used in the query

Comment: @extreme4all did u try taking off distinct clause, you wont  need it as you are using group by

Comment: @BHouse i've tried that, i do need the distinct since the dbo.merge contains all users with every entitlement of every role.

Comment: Looking at your plan that you shared, thank you, I see that you have an EAGER SPOOL and SORT plan operators, following directly after the PK_MERGE_ID SCAN. 

Both of these operators are blocking Operators, i.e the execution of the query doesn't continue until blocking operators have done their thing.

Can you share the plan with the Non clustered index created?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze i have shared it

Comment: Change your index to `create nonclustered index test
on dbo.[Merge] (FTM, centralaccount DESC)
include ([Fachteam],[TEM],[Team],[ABT],[Abteilung],[BER],[Bereich],[GB],[Geschaeftsbereich],[KB],[Konzernbereich], [rol naam])`

Comment: this one does no diffrent from the others; 

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1mtT8_Lf

Comment: No point in creating index.first goal is to write optimize query then move to your where condition part then index tuning.So write query in such a manner that don'tuse count,distinct,group by and yet give correct output.So start your question from here.

Comment: did you try to take out parts of the query and identify when it starts to take longer

Comment: @user4219031 the query starts running slow when i add the where clauses

Comment: it looks like you have a lot of LIKE conditions with OR and AND . Did you consider using full text search?

Comment: yes i did, and this works if the user goes cross report. but the user can also go to the reports direcly and does usualy not know exacly what he is searching for other then maybe the first name or part of the role name, also the user wants to be able to search all role names or teams with 'specific appname'

Comment: i found one of the performance issues; statements similar to these
(
@Role='' and ([rol naam] like '%'+@Role+'%' or [rol naam] is null) or [rol naam] like '%'+@Role+'%'
)

Comment: @user4219031 your reply made me look further into the filters, i realised i could remove alot of the filters because they don't and can't contain null anyway. then i just ended up with the role parameter, a user can't fill in null but we want to see the users with null roles so i made the following; isnull([rol naam],'') like '%'+@Role+'%'. at the end i got a bit better performance of 30 second instead of 50. i wish to hear more idea's cause i believe we can improve it even more

Comment: can you paste the updated query with the new simplified filters?

Comment: @extreme4all what about using CTE for the select without group by, only with the where conditions and then apply the group by to the CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By forcing parralelism i've mananaged to cut down the execution time to 9 seconds, here is an example of a similar query with 3 counts;

```
select distinct
count(distinct a.CentralAccount) as 'Aantal users',
    'Aantal rollen'=(
        select count(distinct [Rol naam])  from DIM.Clean_KeyMerge b
        left join DIM.Clean_User dcub
            on(b.CentralAccount=dcub.CentralAccount) 
        where dcua.[Fachteam]=dcub.[Fachteam] and dcua.[Team]=dcub.[Team] and dcua.[Abteilung]=dcub.[Abteilung] and dcua.[Bereich]=dcub.[Bereich] and dcua.[Geschaeftsbereich]=dcub.[Geschaeftsbereich] 
    ),
    'Aantal entitlements'=(
        select count(distinct EntName)  from DIM.Clean_KeyMerge c
        left join DIM.Clean_User dcuc
            on(c.CentralAccount=dcuc.CentralAccount) 
        where dcua.[Fachteam]=dcuc.[Fachteam] and dcua.[Team]=dcuc.[Team] and dcua.[Abteilung]=dcuc.[Abteilung] and dcua.[Bereich]=dcuc.[Bereich] and dcua.[Geschaeftsbereich]=dcuc.[Geschaeftsbereich] 
    )
,dcua.[Fachteam],dcua.[Team],dcua.[Abteilung],dcua.[Bereich],dcua.[Geschaeftsbereich]from DIM.Clean_KeyMerge a
left join DIM.Clean_User dcua
    on(a.CentralAccount=dcua.CentralAccount)
```